# how to swipe between layouts in one activity using onTouchEvent

Tags: android, android-activity, viewflipper

[swipping between two layouts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGdWM.jpg)I'm newbie android developer and I need to implement an activity with several layouts or frames and I want only one to be displayed at a time.I also want to swipe between these layouts (left or right) using onTouchEvent as it is shown in the picture.
Any suggestion for that?Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are too many tutorials for what you want. All you need is using google to help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this you will have to use Tabs with swiping pages. Create two fragments.

Follow the process.

I think the way you trying to achieve this is an old way.

For sliding pages with tabs do following.

Download or copy following two files on github and paste your project. this is same as on developers.google.com except setDistributeEvenly method.

https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget/SlidingTabLayout.java

https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget/SlidingTabStrip.java

activity_main.xml

```
<your.package.name.SlidingTabLayout
    android:clickable="true"
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
 </your.package.name.SlidingTabLayout>

 <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />
```

MyAdapter.java (Here i used two pages only)

```
class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter  
{  
    String[] title = {"All","Favourites"};
    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {  
        super(fm);  
    }  
    @Override  
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment=null;  
         if (position==0)
            fragment= new All();  
             if (position==1)
                fragment= new Favourites();  
        return fragment;  
    }  
    @Override  
     public int getCount() {  
        return 2;  
    }  
       @Override  
       public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
             return title[position];
    }  
 }
```

tab_view.xml (view of tab only , if you want u can also use ImageView here)

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tab_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text=""
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        />
   </FrameLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
 private SlidingTabLayout tabLayout;
 private ViewPager pager;
 tabLayout= (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);  
 pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);  
 tabLayout.setCustomTabView(R.layout.tab_view,R.id.tab_title);  
 MyPagerAdapter adapter =  new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());  
 pager.setAdapter(adapter);  
 tabLayout.setDistributeEvenly(true);  
 tabLayout.setViewPager(pager);
```

Above code is fine. but latest way to achive swiping tabs with pages is throug android support design library.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would like SwipeViews ( http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/swipe-views.html ). You achieve this by using a ViewPager :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/pager"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

More details on http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html . Happy coding!